# What differential equation corresponds to this vector field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Here is a vector field:$$ \vec F(x,y)=\{\sin(x),\sin(y)\}, $$

where $x,y \in (0,\pi).$

How do you find the differential equation, that when solved gives the integral curves for this vector field? I made this plot on WolframAlpha:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we treat your slope field $F$ as a system of differential equations, we get the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &=F_x = \sin(x) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= F_y = \sin(y)
\end{align*}

The trajectories for an autonomous system of differential equations can be calculated through the following formula: 
$dy/dx =(dy/dt) / (dx/dt)$. Thus, the curves for you slope field will follow the following differential equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{\sin(y)}{\sin(x)}$$
This equation is separable and should be relatively easy to solve.